# do I need a connection.commit() after executeBatch()?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have to check the code of a fellow coworker and I stumble on this piece of code:

```
private void pdate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, List<Long> saisineIdsToUpdate,Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE SAISINES SAI WHERE SAI.IDSAISINE = ?"; //request simplified

    PreparedStatement psUpdate = connection.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);

    for (Long saisineId : saisineIdsToUpdate) {
        psUpdate.setLong(1, saisineId );
        psUpdate.addBatch();

    }
    psUpdate.executeBatch();
    psUpdate.close();
```

The code works, the updates are done correctly, but I cannot find the trace of a `connection.commit();`
I wonder how it can work without the commit - could someone explain why ?

Comment: You must have the auto-commit mode enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-transactions.htm), JDBC-drivers commonly use autocommit, you can enable database-traces via DBMS-driver specific settings like `showSQL` or `generateDDL` in JPA.

> To enable manual- transaction support instead of the auto-commit mode
>   that the JDBC driver uses by default, use the Connection object's
>   setAutoCommit() method. If you pass a boolean false to setAutoCommit(
>   ), you turn off auto-commit. You can pass a boolean true to turn it
>   back on again.

Answer (score 2):

if you set auto-commit on your connection object to false then we have to commit the transaction manually

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
// your code goes here
connection.commit();
```

if you don't set auto-commit then default its value is true and it will commit each record

Comment: Setting AutoCommit to false will not work with Oracle, error yielded will be ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel.